# Trouble downloading a file from a server with a secure connection

Tags: php, apache

Good day!

Faced with the problem of file download from the server. There is such a code

```
function getFile($file)    
{
if (file_exists($file))
{
    if (ob_get_level())
    {
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    if ($fd = fopen($file, 'rb')) 
    {
        while (!feof($fd)) {
        print fread($fd, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fd);
    }
}  
}
```

On the local computer ( worth apache) all performed great , the standard window open / save file. But on the battle server ( configured secure connection , as apache) , nothing happens.

In the Apache configuration file settings have the redirect to https . Maybe the whole thing in https, (In the Apache configuration file to add a line AddType application / octet-stream. Xyz) how can it win ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The entire catch was with permissions on the file to a shared directory